# Catch exception thrown from an async lambda

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am trying to write a method that tries to execute an action but swallows any exceptions that are raised.

My first attempt is the following:

```
public static void SafeExecute(Action actionThatMayThrowException) {
    try {
        actionThatMayThrowException();
    } catch {
        // noop
    }
}
```

Which works when called with a synchronous action:

```
SafeExecute(() => { 
    throw new Exception(); 
});
```

However fails when called with an asynchronous action:

```
SafeExecute(async () => { 
    await Task.FromResult(0);
    throw new Exception(); 
});
```

Is is possible to write a method that handles both scenarios?

Comment: which framework you are using??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To correctly handle `async` delegates you shouldn't use `Action` (this will cause the lambda expression to be `async void` which is dangerous and [should be avoided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)), you should use `Func<Task>` to be able to `await` it:

```
public static async Task SafeExecute(Func<Task> asyncActionThatMayThrowException)
{
    try
    {
        await asyncActionThatMayThrowException();
    }
    catch
    {
        // noop
    }
}
```

This will solve the `async` case, but not the synchronous case. You can't do both with a single method. To do that you would need a different method, but it can still call the `async` one to enable reuse:

```
private static readonly Task<object> _completedTask = Task.FromResult<object>(null);

public static void SafeExecute(Action actionThatMayThrowException)
{
    SafeExecute(() =>
    {
        actionThatMayThrowException();
        return _completedTask;
    });
}
```

---

I wouldn't actually recommend disregarding unhandled exceptions in this way. You should consider at least logging the exception.

Comment: I only just realised some of my unit tests were getting bitten by this behaviour (basically failing Assert's were getting swallowed), surprising there's still no warnings for assigning an async lambda to an Action after all this time.

Comment: Note: In newer versions of .NET there is Task.CompletedTask [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_CompletedTask]

Comment: Ok, why is the async lambda throwing on the calling thread?